# javascript total sum function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sorry all, I'm really trying to learn JS as I'm trying to combine the total sum of the checkbox item selected and also the sum of the item from the radio button selection. My JS is just an attempt but I'm not getting anywhere.

```
 <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Order CDs</title>
</head>
<body>

<script type = "text/javascript">

function isChecked(checkbox, sub1) {
    var button = document.getElementById(sub1);

    if (checkbox.checked === true) {
        button.disabled = "";
    } else {
        button.disabled = "disabled";
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#termsChkbx').change(function(){
        if($(this).is(':checked'))
        {
            $(this).parent('p').css('color','black');
        }
        else
        {
             $(this).parent('p').css('color','red');
        }
    });  

$(document).on("click",".chosen",function() {
        var sum=0;
    var chk=$(this).find("input");
    if(chk.is(':checked')) {
        sum = sum + parseInt(chk.val());
    } else {
        sum = sum - parseInt(chk.val());
    }
    $('#total').val(sum);
}); 

});

</script>


<div id="wrapper">
    <h1>Buy CDs</h1>

    <form id="orderForm" action="#" method="get">
        <section id="selectCD">
            <h2>Select CDs</h2>
<?php
include_once('database_conn.php');
$sqlCDs = 'SELECT CDID, CDTitle, CDYear, catDesc, CDPrice FROM nmc_cd b inner join nmc_category c on b.catID = c.catID WHERE 1 order by CDTitle';
$rsCDs = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlCDs);
while ($CD = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rsCDs)) {
    echo "\t<div class='item'>
            <span class='CDTitle'>{$CD['CDTitle']}</span>
            <span class='CDYear'>{$CD['CDYear']}</span>
            <span class='catDesc'>{$CD['catDesc']}</span>
            <span class='CDPrice'>{$CD['CDPrice']}</span>
            <span class='chosen'><input type='checkbox' name='CD[]' value='{$CD['CDID']}' title='{$CD['CDPrice']}' /></span>
        </div>\n";
}
?>
        </section>

        <section id="collection">
            <h2>Collection method</h2>
            <p>Please select whether you want your chosen CD(s) to be delivered to your home address (a charge applies for this) or whether you want to collect them yourself.</p>
            <p>
            Home address - &pound;4.99 <input type="radio" name="deliveryType" value="home" title="4.99" checked = "checked" />&nbsp; | &nbsp;
            Collect from warehouse - no charge <input type="radio" name="deliveryType" value="trade" title="0" />
            </p>
        </section>

        <section id="checkCost">
            <h2>Total cost</h2>
            Total <input type="text" name="total" id="total" size="10" readonly="readonly" />
        </section>

        <section id="placeOrder">
            <h2>Place order</h2>
            Your details
            Customer Type: <select name="customerType">
                <option value="">Customer Type?</option>
                <option value="ret">Customer</option>
                <option value="trd">Trade</option>
            </select>

            <div id="retCustDetails" class="custDetails">
                Forename <input type="text" name="forename" id="forename" />
                Surname <input type="text" name="surname" id="surname" />
            </div>
            <div id="tradeCustDetails" class="custDetails" style="visibility:hidden">
                Company Name <input type="text" name="companyName" id="companyName" />
            </div>

            <p style="color: red; font-weight: bold;">I have read and agree to the terms and conditions
            <input type="checkbox" id="termsChkbx " onchange="isChecked(this,'sub1')"/></p>


            <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Order now!" id="sub1" disabled="disabled"/></p>
        </section>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the **exact** problem? What is the behavior you expect and what is the behavior that happens instead?

Comment: Also, we don't need to see your PHP if it's working fine, just the rendered output.

Comment: Sorry all, I updated the question again. I'm not able to get the total sum of the items selected by the checkbox & the radio box

Comment: @DoranL check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('.chosen')` is not checkbox. checkbox is child of  `.chosen`

Try like this

```
$('.chosen').on("click",function() {
    var chk=$(this).find("input");
    if(chk.is(':checked')) {
        sum = sum + parseInt(chk.val());
    } else {
        sum = sum - parseInt(chk.val());
    }
    $('#total').val(sum);
});
```

<kbd>**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6dtjd30q/)**</kbd>

Comment: Thanks, it's weird that i can see it work on jsfiddle but not on mine. Does it matter where I place my <script type ='text/javascript"> ?

Comment: @DoranL it's depend on many things. like dynamic dom , static dom , loadtime etc

Comment: @DoranL Most likely it is working in JSFiddle and not on your local instance because you need to wrap your code in the jQuery ready event like this `$(document).ready(function(){ /*Place your code here*/ });`

Comment: @SnareChops Thanks, I already did that.. i uploaded my JS on the questions and the only function working is -> function isChecked(checkbox, sub1)

Comment: @DoranL you don't need mutiple ready event . wrap all method in one ready event and i think you need event delegate.. Try like this `$(document).on("click",".chosen",function()` instead of `$('.chosen').on("click",function()`

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi Thanks, I combine them under one ready event and made the changes. I uploaded on the question but still doesn't seem to work

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi no error on console. I also try creating a new php just with this total sum function but still nothing. Anyway I updated the question with the entire code.

Comment: @DoranL can you make sure that click is firing ?? like put a console.log inside then check the output of sum in console

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi do u mean something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31014701/add-up-array-on-button-click-php-script ?

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi I found an error on debug which says on Line 38 referring to $(document).ready(function(){ -> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: @DoranL you didn't include jquery library file

Comment: Thank you. Just one issue I found it seems the total box is getting the value from "value='{$CD['CDID']}'" instead of  "title='{$CD['CDPrice']". So the value I'm getting is the ID and not the price. Which portion should i change ?

Comment: @DoranL `.val()` fetech from value property . try like this `title='{$CD['CDID']}' value='{$CD['CDPrice']}'`

Comment: Thanks, that work. I notice that it doesn't show the decimal amount and only the first or first 2 digit. I try to change to double but i doubt it works that way. How can i display decimal amount too ?

Comment: @DoranL it didn't show double cz you are parsing it as a int during sum . check this fiddle : **http://jsfiddle.net/6dtjd30q/1/**

Comment: Ok, thanks. But I'm wondering if it makes sense for me to place a value such as 1.25 or 0.01 because it won't show the right total amount.